# function not executing on comparison of two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to get a comparison operator to work, without success. The operator compares two arrays to ensure they are identical.

```
if (($(array_1).not($(array_2)).length === 0 && $(array_2).not($(array_1)).length === 0)) {
    alert("all matches dropped"); 
  }
```

The code works of course with 'true' in place of the comparison.

```
if (true) {
    alert("all matches dropped"); 
  }
```

The strange part is that the comparison returns 'true' when entered into the console:

```
console.log($(array_1).not($(array_2)).length === 0 && $(array_2).not($(array_1)).length === 0)
----> true
```

Any ideas what may be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What's inside `array_1` and `array_2` ?

Comment: _“The strange part is that the comparison returns 'true' when entered into the console”_ – and if you don’t enter it into console, but make the same debug output directly before the `if` statement in your code …?

Comment: You are comparing array length with the value 0 which is falsy. So, in your case array length if is not found then equals to 0, so false = false returns true.

Comment: Why are you not using just like this? `$(array_1).length === 0 && $(array_2).length === 0`

Comment: lookup the jquery's not operator

Comment: if($(array_1).not(array_2).length === 0 && $(array_2).not(array_1).length === 0) before the if statement returns false. In the console it returns true.

Comment: array_1 = ["t(8;14)(q24;q32)", "t(14;18)(q32;q21)"] ; array_2 = ["t(14;18)(q32;q21)", "t(8;14)(q24;q32)"]

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if($(array_1).not(array_2).length === 0 && $(array_2).not(array_1).length === 0)
```

Instead of:

```
if (($(array_1).not($(array_2)).length === 0 && $(array_2).not($(array_1)).length === 0))
```

Here `$(array_1).not(array_2).length` and `($(array_1).not($(array_2)).length` both are not the same thing.